# GIT pull specific file from trunk/master to overwrite local "change"

Tags: git

Our trunk is called "master" and I've done a `rebase` though there is a file "conflict" on the very last line:

Removed:

```
}
```

Added:

```
}
```

How do I force GIT to pull *just* the "conflicted" file to overwrite the local copy so I can do a clean `rebase`? I do *not* want to blindly overwrite everything or lose untracked files.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to `git rebase --skip` to skip that patch or
You resolve it and then `git add <path>` the file followed by a `git rebase --continue`.